# Jquery disable accordion tab base on URL

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-accordion

i have following JQuery code:

```
    var activeIndex = parseInt($('#<%=hidAccordionIndex.ClientID %>').val());

$("#accordion").accordion({
                header: "h3",
                navigation: true,
                icons: false,
                active: activeIndex,                
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    icons: false;
                }
    });
```

it is working fine. now I want enable/disable certain tabs based on URL parameter. if user type http://example.com/mypage.aspx?key=profile than page should have only tab # 3 and # 4 enable all other tabs should be disable. if other key value than some other tab will be enable. if no key value in URL than all tabs should be enable.

I googled and show many examples but none of them is solving my problem. please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution. posting here, may be useful to someone else.

in .css add:

```
.ui-accordion-header-disable 
{
    background-color:#dddddd; 
}
```

in .aspx add this class to the header that you want to conditionally disable:

```
   <div id="accordion">
       <div class="ui-accordion-header-disable ">
          <h3 id="acc_email"><a href="#"><span style="font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold">E-mail</span></a></h3>
            ....
         </div>
```

write script:

```
<script id="scriptInit" type="text/javascript">


            $(document).ready(function () {

                var key = getParameterByName('key');

                if(key == 'passwordchange')
                    $('.ui-accordion-header-disable').addClass('ui-state-disabled').unbind('click');
                else
                    $('.ui-accordion-header-disable').removeClass('.ui-accordion-header-disable').bind('click');                   

            });

            ....

    </script>
```